# I want to shorten datetime in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

so, I noticed in my cshtml file, a lists datasource, and the schema looks a bit like this:

```
model: {
    fields: { 
        claimId: { type: "number" }
        serviceDate: { type: "string" } 
    etc....
```

So I changed service date to

```
model: {
    fields: { 
        claimId: { type: "number" }
        serviceDate: { type: "date" } 
    etc....
```

which fixes the sorting issue I was having, however--this changes the data that is being displayed from looking like:

10/15/2015 to "Thu Apr 15 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" or something like that.  How can I return this back to a shorter date time?

Comment: Can you format this in the Template: " "?

Comment: Is this really how you .cshtml looks? Also, I would assume that you needed a model class with a serviceDate property?